# Нужно поменять местами цвет с фоном при наведение на button

Tags: css3, html5

При наведение (:hover), фон меняется на синий, текст на белый, а вот букву "F" которую я залил картинкой(по дефолту белая, но мне нужна она синяя без наведение мышкой), не меняет цвет, посоветуйте в каком формате делать картинку и как менять ее цвет при наведение на кнопку?

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}

.fbSocial_footer{
  color: #3C5A99;
  margin-left: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: solid #3C5A99 2px;
  width: 158px;
  height: 43px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fbFooterTitle{
  font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.fbSocial_footer:hover{
  background-color: #3C5A99;
  color: #D1D8E7;
}

.fbSocial_footer img{
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fbSocial_footer max">
    <div class="fbFooterTitle">Facebook</div>
    <img src="facebook_symbol_deks.png" alt="" class="">
  </div>
```

[image: Кнопка]

При наведение (:hover), фон меняется на белый, текст на синий, а вот букву "F" которую я залил картинкой, не меняет цвет, посоветуйте в каком формате делать картинку и как менять ее цвет при наведение на кнопку?

Comment: для этого применяют шрифтовые иконки и не изображения

Comment: Спасибо, вот в чем проблема была

Answer (score 2):

Как то так.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.fbSocial_footer {
  color: #3C5A99;
  margin-left: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: solid #3C5A99 2px;
  width: 158px;
  height: 43px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fbFooterTitle {
  font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.fbSocial_footer:hover {
  background-color: #3C5A99;
  color: #D1D8E7;
}

.fbSocial_footer img {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="fbSocial_footer max">
  <div class="fbFooterTitle">Facebook
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: я о этом и сказал ему , плюс тебе от меня

Comment: спасибо, теперь буду знать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Благодарю, за `+`, синхронно ответили. :)  плюс за коммент.